# I have PersistentBag class but need ArrayList class

Tags: java, hibernate, arraylist, junit5

I am trying to write simple Pet-project, I use Hibernate in DAO layer. I have entity Group with field Students.

```
@Data
@AllArgsConstructor
@RequiredArgsConstructor
@EqualsAndHashCode
@ToString
@Builder
@Entity
@Table(name = "groups")
@NamedQueries({ 
    @NamedQuery(name = "get all groups", query = "from Group"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "find group by id", query = "select g from Group g join fetch g.students where g.id=:groupId"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "find group by name", query = "from Group g where g.name like :groupName"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "find number of groups", query = "select count(*) from Group"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "find group and sort by name", query = "from Group order by name, id"),
    @NamedQuery(name = "find group and sort by id", query = "from Group order by id")
})
public class Group  {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column
    private int id;
    
    @Column
    private String name;
    
    @OneToMany(cascade={CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.REFRESH})
    @JoinTable(
            name="studentsGroups",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="groupId"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="studentId")
            )
    @LazyCollection(LazyCollectionOption.FALSE)
    private List<Student> students; 
}
```

in DAO layer for exaple I have method

```
@Transactional
    public Optional<Group> findById(int groupId) {
        Session session = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return Optional.ofNullable(session.get(Group.class, groupId));
    }
```

I want to check my DAO and I am writing junit test. I use assertThat to compare entity from database and entity  from test data. In test data, field students have type ArrayList but from Hibernate get type PersistentBag and I can't compare these fields although all data are same.

```
@Test
    public void givenFindGroupById_whenFindGroupById_thenGroupWasFound() {

        Optional<Group> actual = groupDao.findById(2);

        assertThat(actual).isPresent().get().isEqualTo(expectedGroups.get(1));
    
    }


List<Group> expectedGroups = Arrays.asList(
            Group.builder().id(1).name("a2a2").students(expectedStudentsForGroupA2A2Name).build(),
            Group.builder().id(2).name("b2b2").students(expectedStudentsForGroupB2B2Name).build(),
            Group.builder().id(3).name("c2c2").students(expectedStudentsForGroupC2C2Name).build(),
            Group.builder().id(4).name("d2d2").students(expectedStudentsForGroupD2D2Name).build());
```

Is there some way to convert  PersistentBag  to ArrayList, or I am doing something wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PersistentBag uses Object's equals method  for equals() and hashCode() [Bug](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-5409).

FIX:
Exclude students field for equals check by adding @EqualsAndHashCode.Exclude over it. 
Now assert the Students values: `assertThat(actual.get().getStudents()).containsOnlyElementsOf(expectedGroups.get(1).getStudents())`